# How to extract timestamp from log itself in Loki

Tags: timestamp, grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, promtail

There is a time filter by default in grafana dashboard. It filters by the time the log was sent to grafana from loki. I want to change that time to the timestamp in the log (a label). Is it possible and if yes how?

I am expecting to filter the logs by the timestamp on my log rather than the time the log was sent to grafana.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that time when log occurred, and time when it was sent to Loki differ, I assume you are using [Promtail](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/) as a log scraping agent.

Promtail provides a stage `timestamp` exactly for this reason: to replace associated timestamp. From [official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/stages/timestamp/):

> The `timestamp` stage is an action stage that can change the timestamp of a log line before it is sent to Loki. When a `timestamp` stage is not present, the timestamp of a log line defaults to the time when the log entry is scraped.

A couple examples of how this stage can be used are listed in the [Promtail configuration overview](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/send-data/promtail/configuration/).

Comment: the timestamp in my log is like:
"2024-03-06T09:22:45.040+0530"
i kept the timestamp stage like:

    - timestamp:
        source: time
        format: "2024-03-06T09:22:45.040+0530"
but i am not getting the same time as the timestamp label and the grafana timestamp.

Comment: I believe this is an RFC3339 format, so you can use `format: RFC3339`. Did you parse your time to be in the label `time`, for promtail to understand which string to parse as you format?